# Windows 7 Task Scheduler & Python - Wallpaper doesn't change

Tags: python, windows-7, scheduled-tasks

I am attempting to run a Python script every five minutes to update a Windows 7 desktop background. It runs perfectly when started from the command-line, but not as a scheduled task.

The relevant code:

```
import ctypes

# According to MSDN/other websites
SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20
# Update wallpaper
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, pathToWallpaper, 0)
```

The scheduled task runs, and my temporary .bmp (at pathToWallpaper) is created, but the desktop doesn't update. I've tried changing the task permissions to no avail.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You're missing the wallpaper rotation feature built into Windows 7. ;)

Comment: I'm updating the same image every five minutes, so that feature sadly doesn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that the scheduled task is running with the same privilege as you.

Comment: Solved! Must run only when user is logged in.