# Trigger Next Wallpaper in Windows 7?

Tags: python, windows, windows-7, wallpaper

How to trigger the 'Next Background Image' option for a Windows 7 wallpaper image? You can dynamically set an image using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4404771/541208) but I'd like to have Windows do the work for me.

[Windows API to trigger wallpaper shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9853393/541208) seems to use some sort of ActiveDesktop solution, but it's in C#.

Currently, I've just made a shortcut to the following (python) code to click on, saving me a right click.

```
import win32api, win32con
import SendKeys

def click(x=-1,y=-1):
    oldX, oldY = win32api.GetCursorPos()
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP,x,y,0,0)
    win32api.SetCursorPos((oldX, oldY))        

click(x=1920)
SendKeys.SendKeys('N')
```

Comment: It's been 5 long years of next-wallpaper-triggering famine since this question has been posted. It sounds like you were looking for something non-.Net, but I've posted a powershell answer [on the question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49023492/356887) if the desire is for a quick script.

Comment: The question is tagged `python`, so not sure the edit is warranted! That said, thanks for the suggestion but I think I'm still looking for a non hacky way of doing it, without interupting my flow.

Comment: Yeah, I just added the "(python)" cause I missed the tag and was about 5 minutes into trying to run it as C# before I realized it.